# SQL Join result table as alias

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is there a way to give a result table of a join an alias?

Example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.num = t2.num
AS result;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes!

```
select result.* 
from (SELECT *
    FROM t1
    JOIN t2
    ON t1.num = t2.num) result
```

You do need to watch where you've got columns of the same name in both the inner tables; you'll get an ambiguous column error for num in the results table. Instead of select * its a good idea to pick out the ones you want.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ` result.* `. What is that?

Comment: That is your alias for the 'table', your join on t1 and t2. That can be anything you like. So you name the alias after the close bracket then reference it in your select or any further joins

Comment: Ah, so where select * is 'give me everything from everything', select results.* is 'give me everything from the results table/alias'. You can go select t1.*, t2.* and it will bring them back. Pretty handy if you have a lot of joins but only want to look at the main tables and ignore the rest

Comment: In your example above, select * will bring back the same data, it was just to demonstrate that you count referencing it by the alias / treat it like a table

Comment: I try this:"select c.* from (select * from o join p on o.id=p.id) as c" on MySQL 5.6, it reports error "duplicate column id". why?

Comment: because O and P have a column that has the same name, at least 'id'. I'd recommend just picking out the columns in your subquery you are interested in : `select c.* from (select o.goose, o.id, p.donkey from o join p on o.id=p.id) as c`

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a table expression (sub-query) and give that an alias, but in your simple example I don't see what benefit it could add. I assume you're going to use this in a more complex query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.category, t2.subcategory
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
) AS result
LEFT JOIN t3 ON result.id=t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT result.* FROM 
(SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2
ON t1.num = t2.num) AS result;
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with ` result.* `. What is that?